# linux print to STDOUT and redirect to a file using single command

Tags: linux, csh

Is there a way to both echo the output of a command to the terminal and redirect to a file using a single file rather than using 2 separate commands in csh (for historical reasons i must use csh for this purpose). Currently I do this

```
echo "Hello World!"
echo "Hello World!" > textfile

echo "next line blah blah"
echo "next line blah blah" >> textfile
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what `tee` is for:

```
echo "Hello World!" | tee textfile
```

For multiple outputs, you can use

```
(
  echo "Hello World!"
  echo "next line blah blah"
) | tee textfile
```

or use the append option with `tee`.

```
echo "Hello World!" | tee textfile
echo "next line blah blah" | tee -a textfile
```

Comment: Excellent solution thanks. The -a flag also lets me append to an existing file